# Generalizing the commutator and anti-commutator

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

I was wondering if there's any attempt to generalize the commutator for something general for more than two terms.

Here's what I was thinking of, for $[A,B]=AB-BA$, so for three terms:

$[A,B,C] = ABC+BCA+CAB-BAC-CBA-ACB$

where I have taken a plus sign for a cyclic permutation of $ABC$, and a minus sign for acyclic permutation of $ABC$.

Is such a generalization still called commutator or something else?

Comment: A little remark: Your $[A,B,C]$ is invariant under cyclic permutations by definition and $[A,B,C]+[B,A,C]=0$ is the Jacobi identity.

Comment: @arsmath I usually first ask and then edit only if the author doesn't react. Also I expected the author to add the setting (associative rings...) (For cleaning I'll erase this comment, please do the same with yours.)

Comment: Of course, there is the "associator" $[x,y,z]:=(xy)z-x(yz)$, which is identically zero if and only if the ambient algebra is associative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This generalization is called a ternary commutator, and there are $n$-commutator generalizations, as explained [here:](http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.6312)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It should be  noted that commutator has been generalized to congruences for
results in universal algebra.  Look up reviews of "Commutator Theory For Congruence
Modular Varieties" by Freese and McKenzie.  Many far-reaching results are
obtained by considering a commutator operation on congruence lattices.